# KafkaStreams not reading messages from kafka in the beginning

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
@Bean
    public KafkaStreams kafkaStreams(KafkaStreamsConfiguration streamsConfig) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 1);

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        
        KStream<String, String> kStream = builder.stream("input-topic", Consumed.with( Serdes.String(), Serdes.String() ));
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        // Use mapValues to parse JSON and extract the timestamp
        kStream = kStream.mapValues(value -> {
            try {
                JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(value);
                long timestamp = jsonNode.get("timestamp").asLong();
                long tenMinutesAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() / 60000; // Current time in minutes
                if (timestamp <= tenMinutesAgo) {
                    log.info("paased timestamp: " + timestamp);
                    log.info("original tenMinutesAgo: " + tenMinutesAgo);
                    return value; // Keep messages that match the criteria
                } else {
                    return null; // Filter out messages that don't match the criteria
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }).filter((key, value) -> value != null); // Remove messages that failed parsing

        kStream.to("output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        kafkaStreams.start();
        return kafkaStreams;
    }
```

In input-topic I pass

```
{"timestamp": "28285312","id":"time01"}
{"timestamp": "28285420","id":"time02"}
{"timestamp": "28285412","id":"time05"}
{"timestamp": "28285412","id":"time03"}
{"timestamp": "28285412","id":"time04"}
```

In output-topic, It check for the latest message timestamp with current timestamp, if it is less than or equal to current timestamp then it goes to output-topic. So, here 3rd timestamp is greater than current timestamp so it does not move to output topic but once it reaches the same timestamp as third one, kafkastream does not pick and put in output-topic.

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka Streams, there's a static `consumerPrefix()` function that must be added to modify consumer client properties.

Otherwise, you must pass `consumer.auto.offset.reset` as the property key.

Otherwise, Kafka Streams consumes data in the order that the producer wrote the data. Your timestamp field isn't really relevant since producers can easily send data out of order, and you should use Kafka Streams windowing functions with a TimestampExtractor against the actual record timestamp, instead of data encoded in the value

Comment: I passed props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); but still once I reach a specific timestamp, the message in the kafka(which is mid) is not pushed to 'output-topic', why?

Comment: I need to read all the messages in kafka everysecond from beginning

Comment: 1. As mentioned, for Kafka Streams you need `consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG)` 2. Disable auto commits and dont manually commit. You need a consumer object, not Kafka streams to use `consumer.seekToBeginning` - https://kafka.apache.org/35/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html